# Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this tiny Postscript image file?

Tags: image, ghostscript, postscript

I am trying to programmatically create Postscript files in an embedded system.
Everything has been going fine until I tried to add an image.
My tiny test file results in an error when I test with GhostView or Ghostscript under Ubuntu.

My tiny example (which should show two grey lines each 15 pixels wide) is:-

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0
%%Title: Example

100 200 translate
15 2 scale
15 2 8 [ 15 0 0 2 0 0 ]
currentfile /ASCII85Decode filter
%%BeginData:          158 ASCII Bytes
image
^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$
^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$
%%EndData
showpage
```

...but I get the following gs error:-

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.05 (2012-02-08)
Copyright (C) 2010 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Error: /undefined in page
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1910   1   3   %oparray_pop   1909   1   3   %oparray_pop   1893   1   3   %oparray_pop   1787   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1160/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:77/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Current file position is 335
GPL Ghostscript 9.05: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

**UPDATE**

Worked out what was wrong ... I'm missing the final "~>" off the end of the ASCII data.  I've added that and increased the "BeginData" byte count to 160.

So the working file is:-

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0
%%Title: Example

100 200 translate
15 2 scale
15 2 8 [ 15 0 0 2 0 0 ]
currentfile /ASCII85Decode filter
%%BeginData:          160 ASCII Bytes
image
^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$
^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$~>
%%EndData
showpage
```

Comment: What command did you run?

Comment: I simply ran:-

gs ps_image.ps

Answer (score 2):

As you've already discovered, the ASCII85Decode filter requires a `~>` sequence in the source to indicate the end of the ASCII85 data. This is detailed in the PLRM 3ed p.131 in the details for the ASCII85Decode filter, and also in an example on p. 84.

For "small" images where the entire data will fit within the implementation limits for a string, you can simply use the syntax for an ASCII85 string and avoid the `filter` entirely.

```
100 200 translate
15 2 scale
15 2 8 [ 15 0 0 2 0 0 ]
<~
^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$
^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$^qdb$
~>
image
showpage
```

BTW, the line

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0
```

doesn't declare the language level (as many believe) but the DSC conformance level. It looks like you're using some DSC comments, but unless you're using them consistently and completely it's not accurate to declare that the file conforms. Just my opinion on this comment. For handwritten code, you can use simply

```
%!
```

as the first line.